# How to open a remote radio stream with ffmpeg's `avformat_open_input` without segfault?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I'm at the beginning stage of writing a small app to stream internet radio stations. For the moment I'm just trying to get the detected info of the input stream. Whilst I am successful in getting all the stream's details via the the command line tool (`ffmpeg -i ${URL}`), calling the library's `avformat_open_input(...)` method call results in a SEGFAULT (a stack overflow to be precise when checked in valgrind).

Passing a local file url works fine though in both the command line utility and the library call.

Here's a minimal example:

```
int test() {
    const char      * station_url = "http://stream.srg-ssr.ch/m/rsc_de/aacp_96";
    const char      * test_file   = "test.mp3"; //works
    AVFormatContext * av_ctx      = avformat_alloc_context();
    int               ret         = 0;

    avformat_network_init();

    if( ( ret = avformat_open_input( &av_ctx, station_url, NULL, NULL ) ) < 0 ) { //SEGFAULT   
        printf( "Could not open file '%s': %i", station_url, ret );
        return -1;
    }

    printf( "Format %s, duration %ld us", av_ctx->iformat->long_name, av_ctx->duration );

    avformat_network_deinit();
    return 0;
}
```

If anyone with experience in dealing with acquiring remote streams using *ffmpeg* libraries in C has some insights I'd be grateful. Thanks in advance.

I'm using **ffmpeg v4.3.1** on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else dipping their toes in the C language:

So, funny story... the name of the calling method I used was `connect()` and that seems to clash with something in the ffmpeg library (likely the network socket connection call) that is not explicitly exposed by the `avformat.h` header. Once I changed the method name things started to work... -_-'

One of the pitfalls of the C language when you have a background in languages that have namespaces.